# Why did my Add View window on ASP.net MVC has changed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application. After I updated some libraries, the screen to add new view changed.

With the new screen, I can't create a view with a model class different than the one present in the drop down list.

Can someone indicate to me why did the screen changed ? 
Can I change it back to the old one.

Thank you very much!

Edit : The second screen is how it used to be.

[image: Screen]
[image: Before]

Comment: Are you asking why the model dropdown is disabled?

Comment: No, I am asking why did this window changed from before. The problem I am having now with this window is that I am never able to create a view with a model of type "string" or "IEnumerable<something>". I am only able to choose from the dropdown which reflect what my Models folder have.

Comment: You're using entity framework which uses models and needs a data context. That's what the two new drop downs are used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model is a simple object (string, or whatever), that means you don't have much to scaffold.  You can simply scaffold an empty template, then change the type from dynamic to string.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this now it is working well. But I am still confused why the window changed, because with the previous window I could set as a model whatever I wanted.

Comment: @HectorTwist - I don't know either, I don't typically use scaffolding, especially for simple types.. so I hadn't noticed when this happened.